# What's the word that combines inclusion/exclusion?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

Like visibility combines show/hidden, what's the word that combines inclusion/exclusion?

EDIT: 
The problem is inspired by the VIM reference manual:

> A character motion is either inclusive or exclusive.  When inclusive, the
>       start and end position of the motion are included in the operation.  When
>       exclusive, the last character towards the end of the buffer is not included.
>       Linewise motions always include the start and end position.

I want to know what's the right word to use for describing the inclusive/exclusive property of a character motion, which I thought is like visibility to show/hidden.

As RegDwight said, I am looking for the hypernym for inclusion/exclusion for this content/condition. Sorry for my poor and misleading English.

Comment: I would use "inclusivity", 'though many might say this is stretching its proper meaning.

Comment: It appears that two other people (**@mickyf** & **@FumbleFingers**) and yours truely (see below) have all landed on the usage of **inclusivity** as your hypernym for this state. Also **@j_random_hacker** has mentioned this word in their answer although not as as a suggestion. I detect a trend. :)

Comment: as a VIM user, I endorse @O.M.Y.'s recommended neologism `clusivity`. The  VIM character operation distinction is  similar concept to that of an open/closed interval in mathematics. I see the term `clusivity` used only very sparsely on the internet relating to real number intervals, but the term does have cachet in linguistics for referring to pronoun systems that distinguish between inclusive and exclusive first-person pronouns.

Comment: I second that the purpose is the determining factor such as visibility, rsvp, covered, or contain.

Comment: Couple more: within or "is".

Comment: I was looking for a word for my documentation that means either exclusion or inclusion but couldn't think of one.. saddens me to say, it seems after reading this nobody else could either :( ... I used "clusion" as a place holder but I found that word to be a little clunky. Might end up using as at least in my head I know what it means.

Answer (score 13):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a [hypernym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy) of *inclusion* and *exclusion*. Without further context, it is quite hard — if not impossible — to provide a definite answer. There are lots of potential candidates (say, *composition*, *content*, *form*, *comprehension*, *constitution*, *policy*, *condition*...). Going by etymology alone, *in-/ex-* + *claudere* (shut in/out), *closure* would be yet another candidate.

**Edit:** now that you have provided some context, you have actually answered your own question. Look at the very first sentence of the quote:

> A character motion is either inclusive or exclusive.

So, in this case, the hypernym of *inclusive/exclusive* is **motion**. The visibility can be either "show" or "hide"; the motion can be either "inclusive" or "exclusive".

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations **Jichao**, you have prompted the creation of a new word! I think the word that would be most equivalent to "visibility" in this context might be "**clusivity**" which does not actually exist at this time.

Seeing that *invisibility* and *visibility* are antonyms, logically the word [inclusivity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/inclusivity) should have an antonym as well and thus *clusivity* is born.

Consider if you will that *inclusivity* is a relatively new word (significant usage begins circa 1930) representing the label for a policy created in response to the elitist concept of *exclusivity*. My suggestion of course would lead to two different antyonyms for one word but that is not unique in English.

Of course since this is computer related you could also just use boolean logic and choose to use **inclusivity** for your hypernym, as in **inclusivity (state) = true / false**. This would not be a new word but could possibly be new usage of the word.

---

**ALTERNATIVELY:**

A very interesting question. I approached this from an etymological perspective and found the following (PIE = Proto-Indo-European):

- **include**: from the Latin *includere*: "to shut in"

   from *in-*: "in" (from PIE root *en*: "in") + *claudere*: "to shut / close" 

   related to *enclose* (from Old French *enclore*: "surround / contain / confine")
- **exclude**: from the Latin *excludere*: "to shut out"

   from *ex-*: "out" (from PIE root *eghs*: "out") + *claudere*: "to shut / close"

These in turn led me to explore similar words:

- **seclude**: from the Latin *secludere*: "to shut off"

   from *se-*: "off / apart" + *claudere*: "to shut / close"
- **occlude**: from the Latin *occludere*: "to shut against"

   from *ob-*: "against / in the way of" + *claudere*: "to shut / close" 

   The Latin "*ob-*" is from PIE root *epi, opi*: "near / at / against"
- **preclude**: from the Latin *praecludere*: "to shut before"

   from *pre-, prae-*: "before / ahead" + *claudere*: "to shut / close"

and finally:

- **recluse**: from the Latin *recludere*: "to shut out"

   from Latin *re-*, intensive prefix + *claudere*: "to shut / close"

After examining these the logical *hypernyms* for the inclusion/exclusion state could be "**shutting**", "**closing**", or (my preference) simply "**closure**". Unfortunately these terms are not intuitive and would require far too extensive an explanation for most people to grasp.

Comment: To clude is to shut or to close. It exists, but it's archaic. O.M.Y. said it correctly. To preclude means to shut or close something off in advance. To conclude means to close something up at the end of sth. So, your conclusion is what closes your argument. To seclude means to be shut off from its surroundings.

Comment: "clusivity" is a linguistic term. https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/clusivity

Comment: 'Clusivity' (the distinction between 'inclusive we' and 'exclusive we') is listed by Wikipedia, YourDictionary, ThoughtCo (Nordquist)....

Answer (score 3):

Inclusion is the [act of including](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inclusion?show=0&t=1286184014) and exclusion is the [act of excluding](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exclusion). Therefore these two words are not an indicative of state like visibility (shown or hidden).

This means that the states are actually "included" and "not included". You could then use the word "Included" itself or maybe the sentence "Is included?" to indicate what you need.

Comment: Inclusion and exclusion can represent either an *act* or a *state*, and in mathematics it also describes a *relationship*. Furthermore the word inclusion also has a *noun* form in science where an inclusion is a body or structure that exists inside another body/structure (although this is a common usage from the more proper *inclusion body* noun phrase).

Answer (score 1):

As Reg Dwight says, OP seeks a [hypernym](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=hypernym&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=hG-bT9SsGanT0QXixYDxDg&sqi=2&ved=0CCIQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2eb548b7ec688333&biw=1237&bih=902) - *a word with a broad meaning that more specific words fall under; a [superordinate](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&tbs=dfn:1&sclient=psy-ab&q=superordinate&oq=superordinate&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3..0l10.84742.84742.1.85372.1.1.0.0.0.0.46.46.1.1.0.zk6Oa8b7xoU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=a50a64a109e6ef07&biw=1237&bih=902).*

But OP himself cites *visibility* as the hypernym for *shown/hidden*, where obviously this simplistic classification merely derives directly from the fact that, in this context, *visible=shown*.

I'm not convinced it's strictly correct to call *visibility* a hypernym at all - it's simply the appropriate noun form for *one of the sub-classifications*. Effectively, a "rule-derived pseudo-hypernym".

By the same token, [**inclusivity**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inclusivity) meets OP's requirement. I note that mickeyf proposed this long ago - but he didn't justify it (even though it's still the right answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite symmetrical, which might not be helping.

```
shown/hidden == included/excluded
```

or

```
show/hide == include/exclude
```

In any case, I think that a possible answer would be `inclusion (included/excluded)`.

Comment: @Bruno's suggestion is probably better, in that (depending on your application) `not included` is not necessarily the same thing as `excluded`.

Answer (score 0):

In light of your update, I would suggest either just `motion` (as [RegDwight suggested](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3647/whats-the-word-that-combine-inclusion-exclusion/3651#3651)), or if that doesn't have the precision you need (insofar as it can refer to the entire action as well as the property of inclusivity/exlusivity of the action), you could use `motion type` or `motion mode`.

When there is no ready-made hypernym available, you gotta build it yourself!  :)

For that reason I would also suggest explicitly defining the phrase before using it.  E.g. if you are updating the VIM manual and want to refer to `motion type` later, then I would add the following sentence before the final sentence in your snippet:

> This property of a character motion is called its *motion type*.